# What is お in お元気ですか?

Tags: translation, honorifics, prefixes

Sorry if this is a very basic question, but I'm trying to understand everything in my first lesson (online, Rocket Japanese).  I don't understand what the purpose of **お** is in the phrase お元気ですか, which is explained as how I ask someone how they are.  I believe 元気 refers to well-being or health, です is roughly the verb "to be," and か is added to turn the phrase into a question.  But nowhere is お explained.  Is it actually required, and if so, what does it add to the question?  On the site it is translated to "how are you?"

Comment: That is formally called "美化語 (びかご)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

お and ご, both represented by [the kanji 御](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%BE%A1), are prefixes that increase the politeness of a word. They are often used when referring to other people to put them on a higher level than yourself, which is why you say 「お元気ですか」 to other people, but you say 「元気です」 about yourself.

Whether you use お or ご is dependent on the word, so ご元気 is not correct. お usually goes with 訓読{くんよ}み readings and ご with 音読{おんよ}み readings. ([source](http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2014/03/21/japanese-honorific-prefixes-%E3%81%8A-and-%E3%81%94-o-and-go/)) This rule is already broken by the word 元気; fortunately the kanji 御 is rarely used, so you usually don't have to guess which one it is when reading.

In addition, there are certain words that usually have お/ご on the front, such as *alcohol* (お酒{さけ}). Some words require it, or would change in meaning or reading without it, like *sorry* (御免{ごめん}), *rice/meal* (ご飯{はん}), *stomach* (お腹{なか}), and *money* (お金{かね}).