# What does お do in ケーキはお好きですか?

Tags: grammar, honorifics, prefixes

> ケーキは**お**好きですか

So I started learning Japanese and something caught my attention quite often.

In some sentences there is an お in front of a verb. What is it doing?

How does it affect the sentence. Can I let the お out?

Comment: Duplicate/related: [What is お in お元気ですか?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36765/what-is-%e3%81%8a-in-%e3%81%8a%e5%85%83%e6%b0%97%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b)

Comment: Even though 好き can be kind of verb-like, most people would say it’s *not* a verb…